# Problema na inclusão de dados através de um form utilizando PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```js
<?php
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USUARIO', 'root');
define('SENHA', '');
define('DB', 'login');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USUARIO, SENHA, DB) or die ('Nao foi possivel conectar');
```

Estou com um problema pra fazer uma inserção no banco de dados, sempre que tento enviar da um erro onde a pagina é redirecionada porem não é efetuada a inserção de fato na tabela,além do mais é um código reaproveitado do mesmo projeto apenas feitas alterações para das inserções e variáveis caso seja útil estou utilizando bootstrap 4 e Jquery 3.4.1

```js
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$produto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['produto']));
$quantidadeLote = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['quantidadeLote']));
$precoCompra = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['precoCompra']));
$preceVenda = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['preceVenda']));
$fornecedor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['fornecedor']));

$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos(produto, quantidadeLote, precoCompra, precoVenda, fornecedor) VALUES ('$produto',
'$quantidadeLote', '$precoCompra', '$preceVenda', 'fornecedor')";

$conexao->close();

header('Location: produtos.php');
exit;
?>
```

```html
<?php
include ('menu.php');
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/painel.css">

<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <h1 class="h2">Cadastro de Produtos</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="container">

   <form action="processaCP.php" action="POST">
     <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label for="Produto">Produto</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="produto" placeholder="Produto">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3">
           <label for="Quantidade">Quantidade Lote</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantidadeLote" placeholder="100">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
         <label for="ComraUnidade">Preço de Compra Unidade</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precoCompra" placeholder="R$0,00">
        </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="VendaUnidade">Preço de Venda Unidade</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preceVenda" placeholder="R$0,00">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="Fornecedor">Fornecedor</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fornecedor">
   </div>
  </div>
  <br> 
  <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Savar</button>
      &ensp;<!-- espaço -->
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
   </form>
   <br>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h3">Lista de Produtos</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
    <span id="conteudoP"></span>
 </main>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/painel.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $.post('listarP.php', function(retorna){
         //Subtitui o valor no seletor id="conteudo"
         $("#conteudoP").html(retorna);
       });
     });
   </script>
```

Comment: poste o erro que ocorre, também inclua os outros arquivos .php

Comment: na sua $conexão, você não está dando commit, não seria isso?

Comment: @danilo o erro que ocorre é: Objeto não encontrado!
A URL requisitada não foi encontrada neste servidor. O link na página referida parece estar com algum erro ou desatualizado. Por favor informe o autor desta página sobre o erro.

Se você acredita ter encontrado um problema no servidor, por favor entre em contato com o webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.6

Comment: quando você clica em Salvar, ele da um post para o "processaCP.php", ele não deve estar encontrando esse arquivo no endereço do servidor.

Comment: mais esse cód é a 'cópia' de um outo cód que funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: a questão não é o código, é o endereço do servidor, por algum motivo ele não está batendo no endereço certo, tente colocar o endereço no browser e verifique se bate nesse arquivo .php

Comment: não acha ele mostra o erro Notice: Undefined index: produto in C:\xampp\htdocs\drogaria\processaCP.php on line

Comment: poste o código do arquivo processaCP.php, verifique com o inspector do Google Chrome ou outro navegador as informações de rede, e veja se ao Salvar ele perde algum link

Comment: o processaCP.php ja esta inckuido é o primeiro código acima do html mais eu vo dar uma olhada no inpertor do google obrigado

Comment: poste o código do arquivo conexao.php, consegue dizer-nos de onde vem essa mensagem de erro que você refere? Objeto não encontrado!

Answer (score 0):

Fala Emerson, beleza?
Dei uma olhada rápida em seu código e notei que ao criar seu SQL, você não informa o ultimo campo como variável, você colocou "fornecedor" em vez de "$fornecedor".

Outro detalhe, não sei se o PHP reconhece a variável de seu texto da forma que colocou, normalmente eu coloco a variável dentro de chaves {}

Você colocou assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos(produto, quantidadeLote, precoCompra, precoVenda, fornecedor) VALUES ('$produto',
'$quantidadeLote', '$precoCompra', '$preceVenda', 'fornecedor')";
```

Dessa forma que você usou não me recordo de funcionar, eu sei que funciona assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos(produto, quantidadeLote, precoCompra, precoVenda, fornecedor) VALUES ('{$produto}', '{$quantidadeLote}', '{$precoCompra}', '{$preceVenda}', '{$fornecedor}')";
```

Espero ter ajudado, um abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Como você disse que o código foi copiado de outro serviço que funcionava, seu problema só pode ser com o usuário do BD.
Verifique as permissões concebidas (leitura, escrita, update, excluir dados, modificar tabelas, etc) que se da ao cadastrar users no MySQL.

DICA: Abandone o mysqli, migre para o PDO (PHP Data Object).